# How to make grunt not parse a template variable?

Tags: javascript, templates, gruntjs

I have Gruntfile.js like this :

```
grunt.initConfig( {
    ...
    host : '/<%= STATICPATH %>/',
    ...
    replace : { 
         dist : { 
             options : { 
                 patterns : [ { 
                     json : { 
                         "host" : "<%= host %>",
                         "path" : { 
                             "static" : "<%= host %>/",
                             "images" : "<%= host %>/images",
                             "js" : "<%= host %>/js",
                             "css" : "<%= host %>/css",
                             "font" : "<%= host %>/font"
                         }   
                     }   
                 } ] 
             },  
             files : [ { 
                 expand : true, 
                 src : [ 
                     '<%= dist %>/**/*.html',
                     '<%= dist %>/**/*.js',
                     '<%= dist %>/**/*.css'
                 ]   
             } ] 
         }, 
    }
} );
```

<%= STATICPATH %> is a template variable in my app but not for Grunt, I want to replace somewhere in my code to this.
But grunt always parse this as grunt template variable. Is there anyway to resolve this problem ?

Comment: Is changing the pattern ( ``<%= ... %>`` ) for the app a possibility ?

Comment: @PrayagVerma i am afraid I can't change the pattern. the project is an old one without a good way to build itself. I want to add grunt into the project, so i got this trouble